# Is it safe to use c++ KillTimer() in middle of timer's execution?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, timer

What will be the effect on a working timer, when during its execution, a [`KillTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644903.aspx) command is sent?

Just to make sure, a working timer means that the timer executes its code.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's no such thing in standard C++. Could you please be more elaborate about your particular framework / OS / programming environment?

Comment: Title says `KillTimer`, question says `killtimer`. What exactly do you use/mean?

Comment: If you're asking about Windows platform, it is safe

Comment: i was talking about CWindow::KillTimer().
are there any helper functions that can give me information regarding a certain timer? time before invoke and so on?

Comment: There is no CWindow::KillTimer in MFC, just a CWnd::KillTimer. CWnd::KillTimer or Windows KillTimer() is safe to call from inside the timer callback function or timer window message handler. I do not know of helper functions for the timers setup with SetTimer.

Comment: Timers don't _execute_ code. Timers _start_ code execution. That's why it's safe to kill a timer after it's started code execution. The only thing you shouldn't be doing is killing it from another thread at the very moment it's starting something, but that's just a special case of not using a single resource from two threads without mutex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Killing a Timer is not the same as killing a thread (which is not safe to kill).

In a Windows system it is perfectly safe.